# Gmail PHP API design understanding

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, gmail-api

I'm trying to get started with the `Gmail PHP client library`. I'm trying to understand the correlation between the language-specific Client libraries and the REST end-points. [The API guid](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/) says nothing about all the methods available through the `PHP Client library`.

> I want to read any incoming messages that contain a specific string

I found a few methods for example

```
// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

// Print the labels in the user's account.
$user = 'me';
$results = $service->users_labels->listUsersLabels($user);
```

and

```
        $optParams = [];
    $optParams['maxResults'] = 5; // Return Only 5 Messages
    $optParams['labelIds'] = 'INBOX'; // Only show messages in Inbox
    $messages = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me',$optParams);
    $list = $messages->getMessages();
```

But I just can't find any library methods to achieve the above goal. There can be some variations of `https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q="in:inbox"`this method but that'll be going the REST end-point way.

- So is it like the REST end-point is the real deal and PHP client library is a helper for authentication but doesn't have all the functions that can be carried out with the REST API?
- IF not, what Client library methods can I use to get the incoming messages containing a specific string?

Comment: I think you should seek for help inside Google Developers help forums. Stack Overflow will serve you better when you already know the stuff you want to do, how to do it (you know the methods and you know how to code it) but you're having issues along the way of getting it done (*I was expecting X to happen, but then Y happened, here is my code, what could be wrong?*).

Comment: @AedixRhinedale I might have submitted the wrong title for the question. Please read the whole question first. The last two pints in the question sum up my question and I find nothing wrong with them

Comment: @AedixRhinedale I don't think you've done justice while describing the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm sorry but if I got you're question right, you're asking *I want to get data from GMail's REST API with a PHP interface provided by Google, but there is not enough docs explaining its methods and proper use. 1) How can I use it to do what I want? 2) Or is there any other better documented interface out there?*. That's why I said what I've said.

Comment: Yeah and StackOverflow is full of such questions, protected by community, upvoted dozens of times to show the question is helpful

Comment: Well, I hope you get your answer then. :)

Comment: Did you look at the [PHP examples](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#examples) in the documentation?